# .before to insert multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element `var destination` which I'm trying to insert multiple elements before it. I use `.before` but I use it multiple times because I'm moving multiple elements.

Is there a way to improve this code, and move all the elements at once? I'm moving an element `moveElement`, the element before it, and a number of other elements that have the class `myClass` using `each()`.  Any way to reduce the number of `destination.before()`

```
destination.before(moveElement.prev());
destination.before(moveElement);
$('div.myClass').each(function(){
   destination.before($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) accepts a jquery object, so you can construct a jQuery object with all the elements.

```
destination.before(moveElement.prev().add(moveElement).add('div.myClass'));
```

[`add` docs:](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

> Description: Add elements to the set of matched elements.